# In accounting, accrual basis, what happens once the client pays to Accounts Receivable and Revenue

Tags: accounting, accrual

From what I understand, in accrual based accounting, when an invoice is issued (not paid yet), two entries are made:

- Accounts Receivable (Debit Entry)
- Revenue (Credit Entry)

But my question is, what happens to above two books when the client actually pays? Does anything change in the above two books? Do other books get affected?

Basically I want to know if Accounts Receivable just grows and grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A payment means the money is no longer receivable, because it has been received, so you'd typically have a pair of entries that moves it from Accounts Recievable (AR) to Cash:

- Debit to Cash
- Credit to Accounts Receivable

Similarly if someone never paid you wouldn't want the balance lingering in AR forever so eventually you might write it off directly as a bad debt:

- Debit to Bad Debts Expense
- Credit to Accounts Receivable